# Upload email attachment using outlook VBA to cloud Store

Tags: vba, email, outlook, dropbox, attachment

Is it possible to make a VBA that uploads the attachment in a particular cloud storage like *Dropbox* or my own *FTP* when I send an Email, my Email recipient will only get the link, so that file size does not make any problem to receive the email.

I want to make something like sharefile outlook add-ons, watch this video: *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5KiqrBR7z3U*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Is it possible to..." Yes, as evidenced by the video you shared. If you're looking for help, please describe what you tried and what went wrong when you tried it.

Comment: Thanks! I think VSTO will be the right way to solve this. I will let you know if I can make it done but unfortunately my office stopped using Outlook. we are using gmail now :P

Answer (score 1):

VBA can be used to automate Outlook tasks. But to get such solution it will be much easier to develop an Outlook add-in. The .Net framework provides all the required classes for implementing your task. VBA has nothing for that out of the box.

See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started quickly.